# Facebook Target Search: Search for ALL ZIP Codes of a City

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

I am trying to retrieve all the ZIP codes of a country with the specific code:

```
$result = TargetingSearch::search(
    TargetingSearchTypes::GEOLOCATION,
    null,
    null,
    array(
        'location_types' => array('zip'),
        'country_code' => 'CY'
    ));
```

I have a problem where the query value should be (the 2nd null)...If I set it to '6', I get all the ZIPs starting with 6.

In my case, I want ALL the ZIP Codes so I set it on null but I get no results.

Does anyone know what I should set to get all the ZIPs?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it accept a wildcard (`*`) character?

Comment: Nop. I tried [0-9] as well with no result as well.

Comment: _“I am trying to retrieve all the ZIP codes of a country”_ - what for? If you wanted to target by country, then you could already do that - so what do you need all those ZIP codes for?

Comment: _“If I set it to '6', I get all the ZIPs starting with 6. […] Does anyone know what I should set to get all the ZIPs?”_ - I guess probably only by making nine more additional requests with the rest of the starting digits, individually …